# Cannot Move a file to other folder if the same file name exist in the folder in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to move a file from its destination to another folder, my codes work properly but if there is already a file with same name exist in the destination folder then it gives error,
my code is given below

```
char * src ="c:\\src\\abc.txt";
char * dst = "d:\\dest\\abc.txt";
if ( rename(src,dst ) )
    perror( NULL );
```

how should i move the file so that it overwrites the file in destination folder. kindly guide me

Comment: You need to remove the destination folder if it already exists.

Comment: isnt it possible that it overwrites the file

Comment: You can use [MoveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function by using `WINAPI`.

Comment: Use Qt not microsoft c++ and its all built in ;)

Comment: @AngryDuck but i am working in Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MoveFileEx( src, dst, MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING );
```

Comment: According to the documentation: _This value cannot be used if lpNewFileName or lpExistingFileName names a directory._ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick to c api then you can use [remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/remove/) function to delete the file if rename will perform a copy:

using your code:

```
char * src ="c:\\src\\abc.txt";
char * dst = "d:\\dest\\abc.txt";
remove(dst);//remove the file first
if ( rename(src,dst ) )
    perror( NULL );
```

Comment: @Barmar: remove will return 0 if successfull no matter whats the state of the file. According to the documentation it can't delete folders, check documentation here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/remove/

Comment: I must have misread something in the question, I'm not sure why I kept commenting about directories.

Answer (score -1):

1) i hope it will work for uuu..

```
    int result;
    char oldname[] ="oldname.txt";
  char newname[] ="newname.txt";
  result= rename( oldname , newname );
  if ( result == 0 )
    puts ( "File successfully renamed" );
  else
    perror( "Error renaming file" );
```

Comment: I am not renaming the file, i am moving a file